# Get rid of useless return statement

Tags: loops, go, return, return-value

I am trying to refactor some code and make it easier to read. I noticed that I have some unnecessary return statements at the end of some functions. Here a **conceptual** example:

```
func someFunction(a []arr) int {
    for _,v := range a {
        if v == something {
            // will defenitly get here at some point! 
            return somethingElse
        }
    }
    return -1 // never ever happens! 
}
```

In my opinion the return statement at the end of the function is misleading, because it suggests, that it may be reached at some point. How do I prevent it?

Please note, that I do error handling at some other point, which is why I can be sure, that `someFunction` will always return `somethingElse`.

Comment: what is the type of `something` we can save that and return it after assigning that a way only required value is returned

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Panic instead of returning fake value at the end of a function:

```
func someFunction(a []arr) int {
    for _,v := range a {
        if v == something {
            // will defenitly get here at some point! 
            return somethingElse
        }
    }

    panic("unreachable")
}
```

This is a common pattern in [standard library](https://golang.org/search?q=%22unreachable%22).

Comment: This is it. Any unreachbable place should panic. The Go compiler even accepts a missing return if a function ends in a panic.

Comment: @GrzegorzŻur exactly :)

Comment: Thank you very for the suggestion. I will do that